# how can i convert data from row to column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how to convert all rows in column A, into EFGHIJK column data, with each 7 rows in Column A becoming 7 separate columns?
[image: how to convert all rows in column A, into EFGHIJK column data, with each 7 rows in Column A becoming 7 separate columns?]

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 (current channel) you can use this formula:

`=WRAPROWS(A1:A24,7,"")`

Comment: how to edit with each data?

Comment: You mean how to change the formula result to values? Just copy and "paste as value".